# How to force MySQL/InnoDB index on term LIKE %...%

Tags: mysql

If you have an indexed field in MySQL InnoDB table (let's call it *term* in here), you can only use:

```
term LIKE 'step%'
```

kind of queries with *%* symbol at the end **if you want index to work**. In other words:

> you can do **indexed search by prefixes only**

There is a workaround for this limitation, that will work in certian cases.

Comment: If you have to scan the entire index because you cannot rely on its order, what would be the performance benefit? (In any case, I don't think it's a bad question.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's a frequent question and I would like to share a trick that I use for SO users.

Answer (score 1):

> **Important!** This is a workaround and it doesn't suit all the cases. But in certain situations it may come in handy.

This workaround helps to save performance, but is paid by using additional amounts of memory.

**Example case**

Let's setup a simple example case:

```
term
------------------
...
Understanding InnoDB clustered indexes
...
```

and user is searching all terms matching the following predicate:

```
term LIKE '%InnoDB%'
```

In case you simplify to *term LIKE 'InnoDB%'*, this phrase will be lost from search.

**Workaround**

1. Introduce *rterm* column that will contain *reversed term*:

   ```
   term                                      rterm
   ------------------
   ...
   Understanding InnoDB clustered indexes    sexedni deretsulc BDonnI gnidnatsrednU
   ...
   ```
2. Add an index to the column *rterm*:

   ```
    ALTER TABLE `t_term`
    ADD INDEX `rterm` (`rterm`);
   ```

   or unique one depending on your case:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `t_term`
   ADD UNIQUE `rterm` (`rterm`);
   ```
3. Apply search by the following predicate:

   ```
   term LIKE 'InnoDB%' OR rterm LIKE 'BDonnI%'
   ```

   where 'BDonnI' is a reversed string for 'InnoDB'.
4. Profit!

**Query plan**

[image]

**MySQL query to fill *rterm* columnn**

MySQL has a handy string function [REVERSE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse). To fill *rterm* column use:

```
UPDATE t_term SET rterm = REVERSE(term)
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't really force the use of indexes for `LIKE %…%` as stated in the question, does it? ;-P

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's definitely not. The question title is designed for this workaround to be found via search. In practice it imitates full index by searching two indices and merging the results.